# How to automatically update model fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

So I have this simple models:

```py
class Room(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Available', 'Available'),
        ('Occupied', 'Occupied'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Reservation(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending')
    )
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS)
    room = models.OneToOneField(Room, on_delete=)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want that whenever I create a new Reservation and assign a room to it, the status field of that particular Room is automatically changed to 'Occupied'.

I think there is a way to do this with Django Signals but I haven't figured out how to implement it on my own yet.

Thanks in advance.

Also, if you think there is a better way to implement said functionality by simplifying or modifying said models please feel free to post it

views:

```py
def room(request):
    rooms = Room.objects.all()
    context = {'rooms': rooms}
    return render(request, 'hotel_app/room.html', context)

def reservation(request):
    reservations = Reservation.objects.all()
    context = {'reservations': reservations}
    return render(request, 'hotel_app/reservations.html', context)
```

Comment: Please show your view code also.

Comment: you need to show your views to get an assistance

Comment: You could change the status of a particular room in your view, after you created a Reservation instance. Also, I think that creating a One to One relationship in room is not a good idea. It means that you have o delete a reservation to be able to link another reservation to a particular room. It would be better if it is a Foreign key relation

Comment: Thank you everyone!. @EduardoMatsuoka Thanks for your suggestion, May I ask how can I change the status on my views? I'm still beginner.

Comment: You should not assign a status to the room, but determine this based on the fact if a reservation exists.

Comment: @DanielEsposito you could get a room by its id and assign to a variable: room = Room.objects.get(id=1) after that, change the room status: room.status = 'Occupied'

Comment: Thanks @EduardoMatsuoka !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think there is a way to do this with Django Signals but I haven't figured out how to implement it on my own yet.

Please **don't** use signals. [Signals are an anti-pattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/). Except for certain cases, it will often result in *more* trouble. Indeed, signals do not run on a lot of ORM calls, especially ones where you create/remove/upate in *bulk*. It furthermore makes saving and updating objects less predictable.

You can simply use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to determine if there are reservations for a given room:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Room.objects.annotate(
    is_occupied=Exists(
        Reservation.objects.filter(room=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
)
```

The `Room` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.is_occupied` that is `True` if a `Reservation` for that `Room` exists, and `False` otherwise.

If you need this often, you can define a manager for the `Room` model that will automatically annotate:

```
class RoomManager(models.Model):
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            is_occupied=Exists(
                Reservation.objects.filter(room=OuterRef('pk'))
            )
        )

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = RoomManager()
```

each time you thus access `Room.objects`, you get a manager that will return a queryset that is annotated.

Comment: This worked for me, also very informative, thanks Willem!